# Получить данные из цикла

Tags: c#, http, vkontakte-api, https, get

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
string resps = GET_http("https://api.vk.com/method/" + method + "?" + paramss + "=" + count + "&access_token=" + token);
```

Как загнать GET запрос в цикл? Проблема в том, что из цикла я не могу получить данные.

Comment: Что значит "загнать GET запрос в цикл" и "из цикла я не могу получить данные"?

Comment: Просто в бесконечном цикле до их обработки интерпретатор не доходит :)

Comment: Покажите больше кода, с этой строчкой особых проблем не видно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
  string resps = GET_http("https://api.vk.com/method/" + method + "?" + paramss + "=" + count + "&access_token=" + token);
}
```

А вообще на странные вопросы - странные ответы. Конкретнее ставьте вопрос